# I need a datasheet for an IC of 8 Pin 3*3*0.9 dimension with Top marking 20042Q Q2KK46 2N1B

Tags: integrated-circuit, automotive

I need datasheet for this 8 Pin IC with top marking 20042Q Q2KK46 2N1B and its Dimension is 3*3*0.9. This IC is used in automotive vehicle Power Conversion Module.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markings and package match with a [Len Technology LN20042Q1](http://www.len-technology.com/en/product.asp?id=112) voltage regulator. The datasheet isn't publicly available, as far as I can tell, but can be downloaded on [Oneyac](https://www.oneyac.net/product/30593256.html) with a registration (only in Chinese though).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much bro. I admire the way you finds the component. Really a great work. I need to learn it from you.